# How to create nested json object in flutter

Tags: json, flutter

// I need to send nested JSON  object to API.This is my API endpoint code;

```
    {
    "type":"PIZA",
    "request_method":"Test",
    "delivery": {
    "category": 1
    },
```

// The source address details

```
    "source":{
    "name":"A road",
    "latitude":"40.6971494",
    "longitude":"-74.2598678"
    },
```

// The destination address details

```
    "destination":{
    "name":"B road",
    "latitude":"40.8516388",
    "longitude":"-73.9109741"
    },
```

// Package Details

```
    "package":{
            "description":"Test sample"
        }

    }
```

// post async request

```
requestAsync(String httpURL, String sourceName, String destinationName) async {
  final response = await http
      .post(httpURL, body: {"source": source, "destination": destinationName});
```

Comment: This question seems too broad can you share how far you have come with a solution, that may simplify the question so you can get the help you need.

Comment: I have implemented this, but l need it nested.                     
    requestAsync(String httpURL, String sourceName, String destinationName) async {
    final response = await http
        .post(httpURL, body: {"source": source, "destination": destinationName});

Comment: Had you setup a model to manage your data. It could ease the process of generating nested dart Maps

Comment: Please yea l  have set up a  model